# Google Dialogflow API REST

Tags: rest, dialogflow-es, unreal-engine5

I am working on a chatbot system, using a Metahuman Avatar from Unreal Engine. I have to somehow connect my metahuman (avatar) to my Google dialogflow agent. I am using standard REST request for this task, but my problem is about the 0auth2. I don't know how to get it done

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "dialogflow.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Agents.GetAgent"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can someone help me get through this or maybe how to disable the 0auth2 verification part

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, Could you follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/identity/oauth2?oauth=code) and let me know if this helps you resolving the issue or not ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh Thanks for your message, I give it a try and still It doesn't work. The thing is I use few platform to get the avatar solution done. Deep brain AI or even the Digital Human from Uneeq. These type of platform only uses the project ID and the json key file to get the connection done with Dialogflow, I guess they are not using the 0Auth2 authentification when they connect to Dialogflow I want to do the same...